# How to model state of leaving/entering home

Tags: design-patterns, algorithms, object-oriented-design, modeling, state

I have two sensors: One detecting if the door is open or closed, another if movement has been detected in the corridor. I want to detect if the person has left or entered  home.
Usually the person has left if:

1. movement detected
2. door opened
3. door closed
4. no movement detected after door closed

Because of the timing problems and the overlapping states (door is open but person also moves) I think the design pattern state is not appropriate here. But I'm struggling to find a better structure.

Any help?

Comment: There are many situations where an absence of any signal **does not** imply the person has left. Not unless your movement sensor covers the bathroom, for example.

Comment: Indeed that is another problem, that could only be solved by another sensor. But I think it is correct to assume if there was movement on the corridor but the door was  not opened, the person is still at home

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a variable with 3 possible states:

- someone at home
- nobody at home
- indeterminate

These states are mutually exclusive, so it will make sense to use them for modeling. Whenever the door gets opened, set the state to "indeterminate". Whenever the door gets closed, start a timer, and when the timer ends, you change the state to "someone at home" or "nobody at home", depending on what the movement sensor told you in the measured time interval. It should be obvious that when the door gets opened again during the time interval, you have to stop the timer and keep the state "indeterminate". You could also consider to set the state to "someone at home" whenever there is movement inside the corridor, even when the door is not opened or closed.

This model takes care of the fact that a person at home might open the door, but does not leave, or vice versa comes from outside, opens the door, changes his mind and does not enter. It will also correct itself when you got the state wrong (maybe because the person left or entered not through the front door), and later measure some movement inside.

Of course, when there is more than one person at home, and only one leaves, this model will get the state wrong, but that is nothing which can be solved by a better model, only by more sensors ;-)

Comment: This seems to be the best - simple, but complete - solution. It also takes of care of 'unexpected' states and so brings a bit certainty to the insufficient sensor data. I've added a transitional state 'may at home' that will hold the timer.

Answer (score 5):

The concept you are looking for is known as ["Hysteresis" (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hysteresis). But don't waste too much time reading the article, as your situation is rather simple.

You have a number of inputs, which have states, and you also have a "logical state" (person in or out of home) which you need to compute out of them.  The "logical state" cannot simply be a direct function of the states of the inputs; instead, your software needs to have a concept of time, and it needs to be able to wait for a certain amount of time after a state transition of any of the inputs before computing its new logical state.

Comment: Ah, you gotta love the silent downvoters.  Apparently they are more knowledgeable, but not nearly eloquent enough to say a word.

Answer (score 1):

State diagram with timing is great way to model your situation.

[image]

This is both understandable and easy to implement. The "movement detected" could be understood as transition from movement being detected to no movement being detected. You could make it better if you had "movement started", "movement ended" and "movement continues" transitions.

Comment: In the state "Idle", is there someone at home or not?

Comment: @DocBrown Is someone home = (Initial number of people - people that left + people that entered) == 0

Comment: The sensors described by the OP will not be able to count how many people are leaving or entering.

Comment: @DocBrown Thats what the purpose of the diagram is. To combine closing, opening, movement and timing events to determine if someone entered and left. You can see there are two events with "/ person entered" and "/person left" in them. If those are executed, then the counts change.

Comment: You missed my point. Whatever model you make, when the sensors cannot distinguish if one, two or three people are walking through the open door, the model will not match reality.

Comment: @DocBrown Of course. But OP was asking only about one person. I believe even himself realizes there is no way to detect multiple people with just sensors he has.